# Can I use the indexOf() to return two different values in a for-loop?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, indexof

```
 String input = "B||B|B";       
 char bridgeMarker = 'B';
 char spaceMarker = '|';

 for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
 {
    int posB = input.indexOf(bridgeMarker, i);
    System.out.println("bridge index: " + posB);
    
    int posSp = input.indexOf(spaceMarker, i);
    System.out.println("space index: " + posSp);

    if(posB > 0 && posB < input.length() && posSp > 0 && posSp < input.length())
    {
        //do something
    }
 }
```

I'm trying to find the index for each occurence of 'B' and '|' in `String input` on each iteration of the for loop.

`int posSp = input.indexOf(spaceMarker, i);` and `int posB = input.indexOf(bridgeMarker, i);` work fine separately but when I use them both I get confusing output:

```
bridge index: 1
space index: 0
bridge index: 1
plot index: 2
bridge index: 3
plot index: -1
bridge index: 3
space index: -1
bridge index: 4
space index: -1
bridge index: -1
space index: -1
bridge index: -1
space index: -1
```

I've been at this for hours and I am so lost so if anyone can give me any advice I'd be so grateful!

This is how I planned on modifying the string values:

```
if(input.charAt(posSp - 1) == input.charAt(posB) || input.charAt(posSp + 1) == input.charAt(posB))
{
    if(input.charAt(posB - 1) != 'R' || input.charAt(posB + 1) != 'R') 
    {
        input = input.replace(spaceMarker, ropeMarker);
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code snippet and the output was totally different and the values of bridge index and space index were correct - so it's ok to use `indexOf` for different characters in the loop.

Comment: That is really strange... I've ran this countless times and am getting the wrong output each time, which is affecting my code further along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that for each index 'i' you are checking the substring starting from i to the end of the String. Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_indexof.asp

Use something like this

```
String input = "B||B|B";
char bridgeMarker = 'B';
char spaceMarker = '|';

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (input.charAt(i) == bridgeMarker) {
        System.out.println("B at index " + i);
    } else if (input.charAt(i) == spaceMarker) {
        System.out.println("| at index " + i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Neither B nor | wos found");
    }
}
```

**Edit**
To use the values in your program, store them in a List

```
String input = "B||B|B";
char bridgeMarker = 'B';
char spaceMarker = '|';

List<Integer> bridgeMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> spaceMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (input.charAt(i) == bridgeMarker) {
        bridgeMarkers.add(i);
        System.out.println("B at index " + i);
    } else if (input.charAt(i) == spaceMarker) {
        spaceMarkers.add(i);
        System.out.println("| at index " + i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Neither B nor | wos found");
    }
}

System.out.println("bridgeMarkers: "+Arrays.toString(bridgeMarkers.toArray()));
System.out.println("spaceMarkers: "+Arrays.toString(spaceMarkers.toArray()));

// how to use them
for (int i = 0; i < bridgeMarkers.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("bridgeMarker nr " + i + " is at index " + bridgeMarkers.get(i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < spaceMarkers.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("spaceMarker nr " + i + " is at index " + spaceMarkers.get(i));
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for just finding the chars but I need to know their index position to compare and modify the character at that index further in my program

Comment: I've added what I planned to do to modify the string to my question, I'm not sure how I could use a list for this

Comment: @Nerf_Herder42 Can you please explain your code in words...  because I don't fully understand your code...  are you basically just trying to replace all | by R ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. There may be some broken logic here... I'm trying to replace | by R so that every B will be next to an R, using the minimum amount of Rs

Comment: So your desired output is "B|B|B" ?

Comment: My desired output is "BR|BRB" - I want every 'B' to be next to an 'R', using the minimum amount of 'R's

Comment: @Nerf_Herder42 I think it would make sense to try some things yourself, using my code as a starting point, and if you get stuck, create a new question specifically describing how the replacement logic should happen. ... don't forget the edge cases
This description will definitely get too long for the comment section.

Comment: I'm definitely going to take another stab at it based on your suggestions. I think the logic behind this has just went over my head to be honest, thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more easily and in a less error-prone way by using Java Regex API:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "B||B|B";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[B\\|]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group() + " => " + matcher.start());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
B => 0
| => 1
| => 2
B => 3
| => 4
B => 5
```

Check [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to learn more about them. You can also check **[Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)** tutorial by Oracle.